# Speed up widget creation with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a little class to create a m x n tabel, of Entrywidgets.

```
from tkinter import*

class Tabelle(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master,rows=3,columns=3,edit=True):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()

        self._rows = rows
        self._columns = columns
        self._edit = edit

        self._entryList = []

        self.createTabel()

    def createTabel(self):
        for row in range(0,self._rows):
            for column in range(0,self._columns):
                _entry = Entry(self)
                _entry.grid(row=row*2,column=column)
                self._entryList.append(_entry)


class MyApp(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack(anchor="nw")
        self.init_widgets()

        self.master.title("")

    def init_widgets(self):
        self.tabelle = Tabelle(self,rows=3,columns=3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = MyApp(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

The programm itself works completely fine, but as soon as I wanna create bigger tabels (like 100 x 100) it takes a long time to create.
Is there a way to speed this up?
I tried to work with threading and replaced
 `self.createTabel()`
with
`Thread(target=self.createTabel, daemon = True).start()`
But I cant figure out how to actually speed it up.

Comment: Use something else. The treeview control can be arranged to present a tabular UI. Creating widgets is relatively expensive so avoid creating excessive numbers of them. 100x100 probably doesn't fit on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are attempting to make a table to simply display data, I think that a `ttk.Treeview` may assist you better, especially if you expect your tables to be that big.  I modified your `createTabel` function to include one.  It certainly needs some tweaking, but it's dynamic, works with your code, and may help you get started.

```
from tkinter.ttk import Treeview

def createTabel(self):
    columns = []
    # loop to create columns
    for j in range(self._columns):
        columns.append(f'col{j}')
    
    # Create the tree
    tree = Treeview(root, columns=columns, show='headings')

    # Loop to define column headings
    for j in range(self._columns):
        tree.heading(f'col{j}', text=f"Column {j}")

    # Nested loops to create your data
    data = []
    for i in range(self._rows):
        lst = []
        for j in range(self._columns):
            lst.append(f'row:{i}, col:{j}')
        data.append(lst) # Each append will be a full row

    # insert all of your data into the tree
    for i in data:
        tree.insert('', "end", values=i)
    
    tree.pack()
```